# $f(x)=g(5x)$, find true statement

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=g(5x)$ for all x, and that both are differentiable.
which is true?
A. $f′(1)=g′(1)$
B. $f′(5)=g′(1)$
C. $f′(1)=g′(5)$
D. $5f′(1)=g′(1)$
E. $5f′(1)=g′(5)$
F. $f′(1)=5g′(5)$
G. $f′(1)=5g′(1)$
or none
i suppose that the true one is C.(seems logical) or none of these.

Comment: By the way, next time please read your textbook again and/or think more before asking a question. It seems that people here think you need to work on the problem more before asking..

Answer (score 4):

Please apply the chain rule.

$f'(x)=[g(5x)]'=g'(5x)(5x)'=5g'(5x)$.

Take $x=1$ we get $f'(1)=5g'(5)$.

So the answer is F.

Comment: Note that any of the other statements *could* be true, depending on the choice of $f(x)$, but F is the only one that is necessarily true.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yep..